# Format output to log filein powershell

Tags: powershell, file, logging

I am writing a function in a powershell script that would write entries to a log file and I am unable to do that in a proper layout.

```
function Write-Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$LogFile, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][int16]$LogLevel,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$SiteURL, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][int16]$ContentType, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$ListName, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$LogMessage
    )

    $LogEntry = New-Object PSObject

    Add-Member -InputObject $LogEntry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Timestamp' -Value [DateTime]::Now
    Add-Member -InputObject $LogEntry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'LogLevel' -Value $global:LogLevel[$LogLevel]
    Add-Member -InputObject $LogEntry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'SiteURL' -Value $SiteURL
    Add-Member -InputObject $LogEntry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ContentType' -Value $global:ContentType[$ContentType]
    Add-Member -InputObject $LogEntry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ListName' -Value $global:ContentType[$ListName]
    Add-Member -InputObject $LogEntry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'LogMessage' -Value $global:ContentType[$LogMessage]

    #$LogEntry = "[$([DateTime]::Now)]`t$($global:LogLevel[$LogLevel])`t$($LogMessage)`t$($global:ContentType[$ContentType])`t`t$($ListName)`t`t$($SiteURL)" | Format-Table -AutoSize 
    Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value $LogEntry
}
```

Apparently, the function above is writing a log entry to a text file, but the format is terrible. I want an array kind of layout where each property is aligned to it's column. For Instance, I want it to look like this:

```
Timestamp                LogLevel          SiteURL         ContentType      
---------                ------------      -------         -----------      
[11/13/2019 09:19:06]    INFO              mysite.org      Document
```

Can you please give me a hand to make this output?

Comment: The mixed usage of globally defined variables while you are also using the values needed to log as parameters (which are local to the function) doesn't make sense to me. Especially since you are defining the `$ContentType` as optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For writing log entry objects to a log file I strongly recommend using `Export-Csv` and a tab-separated log file:

```
$LogEntry | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.log' -Delimiter "`t" -Append -NoType
```

There's always a tradeoff between (human-)readability and parseability, and TSV (IMHO) is the most reasonable compromise there. Users can view the log file with something like this:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.log' -Delimiter "`t" | Out-GridView
```

but even when opened in a text editor it's still sort-of human-readable.

If you must have an output file with fixed columns you probably need to do something like this (using the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx)):

```
'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} {1,-8} {2,-20} {3,-20} {4,-20} {5}' -f $LogEntry.Timestamp, $LogEntry.LogLevel, $LogEntry.SiteURL, $LogEntry.ContentType, $LogEntry.ListName, $LogEntry.LogMessage
```